# How to call the correct ServiceStack service from the string "/rockstars/delete/10000"

Tags: servicestack

I have a string like "/rockstars/delete/10000" which I read from the database, how should I execute it? The result in uninteresting, if a service wants to save something it does it as part of the service, or triggers new services.

Any special reason why null in

```
this.ServiceController.Execute(requestdto, null);
```

isn't allowed, what is the minimum IRequestContext?